# How to fix the Crawl Issue

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, dns, seo, web-crawler

I found  External error 408 when I test my site on  Website Crawler and XML Sitemap Generator tool on below link : 
http://tools.seochat.com/tools/online-crawl-google-sitemap-generator/
My site name like : www.MyWebsite.com
In this error status it show me the created link like  www.MyWebsite.comhttp/  that cause the error . I couldn’t understand how this links is created. Its an Asp.net website which also have a wordpress blog. 
Can anyone please help me to figure out its solution?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

External 408 errors are usually caused by your site timing out.  Do you know of any reasons that can cause your website to timeout?  Also make sure there are not restrictions for the crawler in the Robot.txt file.

Comment: @ Philip
I think the Network Error caused timeout. the link 'www.MyWebsite.comhttp/' may be couldn’t understand by the DNS server that’s why it timeout. I still couldn’t understand from where this type of link created.. do u have any idea about it?

In robots.txt file I have something as below:
“
User-agent: *

Disallow: /faq.aspx
Disallow: /contactUs.aspx

Sitemap: http://www.MyWebsite.com/sitemap.xml
 
“
Thanks.